# Is it possible to have wildcards in the jbehave step?

Tags: wildcard, jbehave

Lets say I have this phrase:

```
When I press save the homepage should be updated
```

can I in my step declare 'homepage' as a wildcard in some way

so my step would look like this:

```
@When("I press save the * should be updated")
```

I can do it the ugly way and just save it as a parameter I don't use as such

```
@When("I press save the $page should be updated")
```

But I think it looks awful. This is just a example phrase so the solution is not to change the text to be more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an outside perspective the $page parameter doesn't look silly since it gives the user an idea of what the step pattern saves but that's just me. And you could add multiple options (e.g. page, homepage, homescreen) with the use of [pattern variants](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/pattern-variants.html).

But to answer your question there is no way of doing this **by default**. At its default [configuration](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/jbehave-core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/core/configuration/Configuration.java), Jbehave uses the [RegexPrefixCapturingPatternParser](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/cd30752c3549aefea43ee60bc813dd36ea953684/jbehave-core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/core/parsers/RegexPrefixCapturingPatternParser.java) to compile and execute a step pattern matching regex (through the [RegexStepMatcher](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/cd30752c3549aefea43ee60bc813dd36ea953684/jbehave-core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/core/parsers/RegexStepMatcher.java)). And unfortunately, before compiling the step pattern regex, regex expressions in the step are escaped:

```java
RegexPrefixCapturingPatternParser.java:

public StepMatcher parseStep(StepType stepType, String stepPattern) {
    String escapingPunctuation = escapingPunctuation(stepPattern);
    List<Parameter> parameters = findParameters(escapingPunctuation);
    Pattern regexPattern = buildPattern(escapingPunctuation, parameters);
    return new RegexStepMatcher(stepType, escapingPunctuation, regexPattern,
            parameterNames(parameters));
}

private String escapingPunctuation(String pattern) {
    return pattern.replaceAll("([\\[\\]\\{\\}\\?\\^\\.\\*\\(\\)\\+\\\\])",
                    "\\\\$1"); }
```

It's probably also worth mentioning that the pattern parser uses the default prefix of `$` to distinguish the start of a step pattern parameter.

If you are very against including the parameter in your step pattern. You could override the default configuration with a StepPatternParser of your own e.g.

```java
configuration().useStepPatternParser(myCustomParser);
```

Comment: I will look in to creating my own parser instead to support what I need here, Thanks for the help.

Comment: I want to say you could probably extend the RegexPrefixCapturingPatternParser and override the escaping punctuation but I'm curious to see how you create it. Let us know